# Attestation Service - what's this data in the URL fragment?

Tags: attestations

The documentation for EAS has a link to this attestation, see long URL bottom. The docs say that this attestation is "completely private" and that "the easscan.org server doesn't even know it exists"!

a) Well, it's hardly an HTTP 404, so how can I tell that it knows nothing about it? It looks normal to me and even has a link to a timestamp transaction.

b) What is this black magic in the URL and where is it documented?

https://sepolia.easscan.org/offchain/url/#attestation=eNqlUUluHDEM%2FEufB4a4k0fPjOcTQQ5aqAcECeDnh93xBwLzUKBYVFEs%2FTjaG%2BpxAwCRgtvRPh%2BoFvv%2BJFvC5P5IDnrB825C2J5ImuAgeZzNBmHLaXVRcRudgQfAImqpgMQ2%2B5w5R99N2trZaCGLMUPiVJiXSJOYROI%2BZfnW3BO7V7JcNmxjcVzWVcB1dszsnEQ7JqyxEdyOG9qpk5nq%2FeORd36PjE3onXVSvGq2035vSDGfr2uodyluiw7aEKFWa3OjQSbcsgEL4xwUAqZdFbgFjVYedIux8N%2FLKTRGVbXPPSKwb%2BElgMZTpqsrw%2BxCzAm9z9UGbEne3vpsjrhPkXJfgwHYXG7tKvz%2B9ScvY74V%2BL3rjcuJWiGsvv0LQbNw6xlUXL38qoCxsYpRYeVVrW%2FEYi4FwWZULJqeWP1cfHVXjxnXWU7mUhqaus2uWViZXHwUwv9vcJSf8PMv1OWspA%3D%3D